# Count all possible paths from top left to bottom right of a m*n Matrix

Tags: php, algorithm, permutation

A person starts from the uppermost, leftmost corner of a grid. Each cell of grid is 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 or 7. From any cell, he can only go to right cell if this cell is 1, he can only go to lower cell if this cell is 2, he can only go to its diagonally opposite cell if this cell is 3, he can go to right and lower cell if this cell is 4, he can go to right and diagonally opposite cell if this cell is 5, he can go to lower and diagonally opposite cell if this cell is 6, he can go to right and lower and diagonally opposite cell if this cell is 7 and he can not move from this cell if this cell is 0.

Person wants to go to the lowermost, rightmost corner of the grid. You have to find number of paths travelling on which he can reach at destination.

Input: 2D array, number of rows, number of columns
Output: Answer

My implementation in PHP:

```
<?php
function process($a,$b, $m, $n, $i, $j) {
    if($a[$i][$j]==1 || $a[$i][$j]==4 || $a[$i][$j]==5 || $a[$i][$j]==7)
        if($j<$n-1)
            $b[$i][$j+1]+=$b[$i][$j];

    if($a[$i][$j]==2 || $a[$i][$j]==4 || $a[$i][$j]==6 || $a[$i][$j]==7)
        if($i<$m-1)
            $b[$i+1][$j]+=$b[$i][$j];

    if($a[$i][$j]==3 || $a[$i][$j]==5 || $a[$i][$j]==6 || $a[$i][$j]==7)
        if($j<$n-1 && $i<$m-1)
            $b[$i+1][$j+1]+=$b[$i][$j];

        return $b;
}

function no_of_path($a,$m,$n) {
    $b=array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $m; $i++) {
        $b1=array();
        for($j=0;$j<$n;$j++) $b1[]=0;
            $b[]=$b1;
    }
    $b[0][0]=1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < min($m,$n); $i++) {
        $b=process($a,$b,$m,$n,$i,$i);
        for($j=$i+1;$j<$n;$j++)
            $b=process($a,$b,$m,$n,$i,$j);
        for($j=$i+1;$j<$m;$j++) 
            $b=process($a,$b,$m,$n,$j,$i);
    }
    return $b[$m-1][$n-1];
}


$a=array(
array(1,3,0,0,0,0),
array(0,0,4,5,1,0),
array(0,0,0,6,7,6),
array(0,0,0,0,5,0)  
);
echo no_of_path($a,4,6);
?>
```

For the input given as sample. the correct answer is 3 which I am getting. But when I tried to submit, it gave wrong answer on very few test cases. The test cases were not disclosed. Could anyone tell me what test case would give incorrect answer? Also if any suggestions for a better implementation?

Comment: I didn't know how ugly php is until now.

Comment: i don't understand php, never coded with php, but from what i could understand from your code you didnt think about DFS(Depth First Search) or any recursive solution right? This can be solved by DFS.

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 edited

Comment: @S_kar I dont think I can apply DFS on this.

Comment: Why not? you can recursively search every solution. Other implementation can be done, but recursive solution is easier to code. Also, other solution might be very tough to implement and may involve a lot of condition checking.

Comment: Please add the original problem link

Comment: @S_kar I think I am able to understand the DFS approach. Something like this:
if($a[$i][$j]==1 || $a[$i][$j]==4 || $a[$i][$j]==5 || $a[$i][$j]==7)
          if($j<$n-1)
                      $b=process($a,$b,$m,$n,$i,$j+1,$b[$i][$j)];

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 I cant post the original link. It was asked in a private contest.

Comment: @S_kar the approach is correct as very few test cases were wrong. Maybe I missed a corner case.

Comment: you know this type of problem requires a recursive solution, this is what is required i think. Also how can you understand very few test cases were wrong? In all OJs if there is one wrong answer, the further cases are not checked.

Comment: I have no idea how to code on php, but i can elaborate the pseudocode if you cant understand.

Comment: Recursive of iterative, it is both OK in this case. I cannot find fault with the algorithm as it is.

Comment: This can be done using `dfs` and `dynamic programming`.

Comment: Yes, but it can also be done as OP has done. The challenge is to see if there is any mistake (if any). The program looks sound.

Comment: You know, usually without implementing a recursive solution, the code will look messy, and you can miss any simple detail, the code looks very messy, it will be hard to debug without the problem statement.

Comment: I think the version of PHP would be relevant for such a scenario, as the coding could potentially benefit from anonymous functions, generators (`yield` instead of `return`), and the SPL Iterator classes. Each of these would require a different minimum version of PHP, some of them may just help make the existing code look "prettier" while others may actually add significant performance boosts and even logical alternatives to the current code.

Comment: Is there a difference between "number of possible paths between two points" and the [Hamming Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) between two points?

Comment: @S_kar in this case the OJ ran all the test cases and showed that 10% of the outputs were incorrect.

Comment: @S_kar I am fine if you can give the solution in pseudocode or any popular programming language. trincot has already given a recursive solution below.

Comment: 10% is a lot don't you think? It seems your algo is fine, but maybe you misunderstood the problem statement. It will helpful if you can give us the link of the problem and any way for submission.

Comment: @TempId, is there a possibility that your interpretation of some terms, like "diagonally opposite cell" is not as is intended?

Comment: @TempId, is there a possibility you mixed up the role of the numbers. I would find it more logical if the role of 3 and 4 were the other way round, because that would match nicely with the bit representation of each number: lowest bit set => you can move right. Middle bit set? => you can move down. Third bit set => you can move diagonally. Such a misunderstanding might well explain 10% test failures.

Comment: @TempId, in fact, I just tried with randomly generated matrices, and if 3 and 4 switch roles, there are 13% cases where these variants give a difference in number of paths. What do you think... did you get that 3 and 4 wrong?

Comment: @S_kar I would have already posted the link if it was possible

Comment: I have posted a link in comments below

Answer (score 3):

I am quite convinced your algorithm is correct, up to the point I would either challenge your correct understanding of the assignment, or the correctness of the test cases which supposedly showed your code to fail.

Here is what I did. I wrote an alternative routine that uses recursion:

```
function no_of_path2($a, $i, $j, $m, $n) {
    if ($i === $m-1 && $j === $n-1) {
        return 1;
    }
    $count = 0;
    if (($j < $n-1) && in_array($a[$i][$j], [1, 4, 5, 7])) {
        $count += no_of_path2($a, $i, $j+1, $m, $n); 
    }
    if (($i < $m-1) && in_array($a[$i][$j], [2, 4, 6, 7])) {
        $count += no_of_path2($a, $i+1, $j, $m, $n); 
    }
    if (($i < $m-1) && ($j < $n-1) && in_array($a[$i][$j], [3, 5, 6, 7])) {
        $count += no_of_path2($a, $i+1, $j+1, $m, $n); 
    }
    return $count;
}
```

Because it is used recursively, you have to pass it the "current" element's row and column as extra arguments.

Note that I did not attempt to make this function efficient, i.e. it is not an example of *dynamic programming*. For that it should store results and re-use them, like you did with a `$b` array. The purpose here was just to have a different approach and see if it would yield different results.

Then I created two utility functions: one to fill an array with random values (0..7), and another to display such array:

```
function random_array($m, $n) {
    $a = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $m; $i++) {
        $row = array();
        for ($j = 0; $j < $n; $j++) {
            $row[] = rand(0, 7);
        }
        $a[] = $row;
    }
    return $a;
}

function echo_array($a, $m, $n) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $m; $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < $n; $j++) {
            echo $a[$i][$j];
        }
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Finally, I put the generation of a random array in a loop, and in each iteration called your function and mine, comparing the results:

```
$n = 3;
$m = 5;
for ($try = 1; $try < 10000; $try++) {
    $a = random_array($m, $n);
    $c1 = no_of_path($a,$m,$n);
    $c2 = no_of_path2($a,0,0,$m,$n);
    if ($c1 !== $c2) {
        echo "difference found:", "<br>";
        echo_array($a, $m, $n);
        echo $c1, "<br>";
        echo $c2, "<br>";
    }
}
echo "done", "<br>";
```

I played a bit with the number of rows and columns, also checking boundary cases, like 1 row and 1 column.

The result is that no deviations are found. Both functions give the same number of paths for all the cases that were generated.

I took third method to calculate the paths, by using formulas in a spreadsheet, one table with the original matrix, and one table with the intermediate calculations and final result. Also there I could not find any difference with the outcomes of your function. You can download that spreadsheet from Google Docs in [OpenDocument format](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HX8ZdJWlwkwGqW6JFn5LpxQ-YIeIs_OZRM4SezAE2HU/pub?output=ods) or [Excel format](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HX8ZdJWlwkwGqW6JFn5LpxQ-YIeIs_OZRM4SezAE2HU/pub?output=xlsx). This, by the way, *is* an example of *Dynamic Programming*.

You said in a comment that 10% of non-disclosed test-cases failed. So either both of the functions (and spreadsheet solution) fail in the same way. This suggests a misunderstanding of the original assignment, or the test cases are assuming wrong answers.

**Some comments about your code**

You could initialise the `$b` array with this shorter code:

```
$b = array_fill(0, $m, array_fill(0, $n, 0));
$b[0][0] = 1;
```

Instead of starting each iteration at cell `$a[$i][$i]` and going horizontally and vertically from there, you can just iterate over the array row by row, column by column:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $m; $i++)
    for($j = 0; $j < $n; $j++)
        $b = process($a, $b, $m, $n, $i, $j);
```

It will yield the same results.

**Potential explanation for the 10% test failures**

I looked at the roles of the numbers. The left table below is what you defined in your question, the right table is what might look more symmetrical: each column represents a bit of the corresponding number, and when it is set the answer is "Yes":

```
    +----------------------+          +----------------------+
    |    Can person move   |          |   Alternative???     |
    | Diag. | Down | Right |          | Diag. | Down | Right |
+---+-------+------+-------+      +---+-------+------+-------+
| 0 |  No   |  No  |  No   |      | 0 |  No   |  No  |  No   |
| 1 |  No   |  No  |  Yes  |      | 1 |  No   |  No  |  Yes  |
| 2 |  No   |  Yes |  No   |      | 2 |  No   |  Yes |  No   |
| 3 |  Yes  |  No  |  No   |      | 3 |  No   |  Yes |  Yes  |
| 4 |  No   |  Yes |  Yes  |      | 4 |  Yes  |  No  |  No   |
| 5 |  Yes  |  No  |  Yes  |      | 5 |  Yes  |  No  |  Yes  |
| 6 |  Yes  |  Yes |  No   |      | 6 |  Yes  |  Yes |  No   |
| 7 |  Yes  |  Yes |  Yes  |      | 7 |  Yes  |  Yes |  Yes  |
+---+-------+------+-------+      +---+-------+------+-------+
```

The only difference between the two tables is that the roles of numbers 3 and 4 are swapped.

With a modified version of the above listed bulk-test code, I compared the results of the algorithm based on the left table with the same algorithm based on the right table. The results are that about 13% of the randomly generated 6x4 matrices give a different result, while all other 6x4 matrices yield the same result.

Would this be a candidate for explaining the 10% failed test cases?

Comment: These were the exact words of problem statement. I had noted down the problem statement on a paper before final submission. Before doing that I tried a case for 1 row and 1 column with 0 and 1 as answer in separate submissions and both gave me wrong answer. Also the leaderboard showed me that there were a few submissions with all test cases passed.

Comment: I added download links in my answer to the spreadsheet solution I mentioned. Again, same results. I also added a section on what I believe could explain the 10% failing test cases.

Comment: I had noted the problem statement on paper before leaving the test center. So it is same as was asked.

Comment: Just trying to give you a potential explanation... one has to think out of the box. It would not be the first time someone made a mistake in copying things on paper. The algorithms are correct according to what you provided us.  There must be another explanation.

Comment: Just now I notice you wrote: *I tried a case for 1 row and 1 column with 0 and 1 as answer* What do you make of that? If the matrix has only 1 row and 1 column, there is only one way to get in the square as you can't even move from it. I think this contest you participated in might be a hoax.

Comment: yes even i think like that. I was just trying to see where I am wrong so I tried 0 and 1 as answers.

Comment: I found a link to this question. The question has same interpretation of numbers. The code is given in Java but I think it is more or less same. This suggests that this code could also be wrong. Here's the link:
http://techno-terminal.blogspot.in/2015/09/count-all-possible-paths-from-top-left.html

Comment: I checked that code, but it does something that is not according to the instructions: when the person arrives anywhere in the last column it is assumed there is a path (return 1) unless the cell has 0. But this is wrong, there might still be zeroes on the way down. The same is done for the last row. That code is wrong. Yours is better.  I left a comment there.

Answer (score -1):

This calls for a nice Dynamic Programming solution, time O(n^2), space also O(n^2) [I am sure this can be optimized to O(n), but lets just focus on the algorithm first].

Assume the matrix is the 2D array A[0..m-1,0..n-1]
For 0 <= i < m, 0 <= j < n, suppose D[i,j] is the number of ways to reach A[i,j]. The optimal substructure formula is going to be long as there are eight different cases:

```
D[i,j] = 0
// Count how many ways to reach A[i,j] from all possible sources
case-1: if A[i,j-1] == 1, D[i,j] += D[i,j-1];  // came by rule 1
case-2: if A[i-1,j] == 2, D[i,j] += D[i-1,j];  // came by rule 2
and so on, ....
also in A[i,j-1] check if j-1 is a valid index, i.e. j>0
```

I cant give the rest of the rules as it is not clear what it means by diagonally opposite cell. Can you send link to the problem page ?

Comment: @Avik Paul the solution cannot be less than O(n^2). Plus my solution is more or less same as you have posted. It only fails roughly 10% of test cases.

Comment: @TempId, OP = Original Poster = you. The algorithm uses two variables, so you cannot say it is O(n²). It is O(n.m).

Comment: O(n) space could be possible if you allocate only two rows of the dynamic programming table. Note that cell A[i,j] needs to lookup only A[i-1,j-1], A[i-1,j], A[i,j-1]. All of them occur in the current row and the previous row. So if you process row-wise and left to right, and after every iteration copy (or swap) the current and previous row. Would it not achieve O(n) space complexity ??